# asyncpg overwrite data in existing table

Tags: pandas, list, asynchronous, asyncpg

Rewriting code from sqlite to postgres.Encountered a connection problem. How to overwrite data?

```
async def get_coins_api_postgres():
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(f'postgresql://{settings.user}:{settings.password}@{settings.host}/{settings.db_name}')
    page = 0
    coin_market = cg.get_coins_markets(vs_currency='usd', per_page=250, page=page)
    df_market = pd.DataFrame(coin_market,columns=['market_cap_rank','id','name','current_price',"price_change_24h","price_change_percentage_24h",'market_cap',"market_cap_change_percentage_24h",'total_volume',  "circulating_supply", "max_supply", "high_24h", "low_24h", ])
    # df_market.to_sql('coins_info', conn, if_exists='replace')
    tuples = list(df_market.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
    s = await conn.copy_records_to_table('coins_info', records=tuples, columns=list(df_market), timeout=10)
    # engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:{}@localhost:5432/coins'.format(settings.password))
    # df_market.to_sql('coins_info', engine, if_exists='replace')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(get_coins_api_postgres())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add after connection TRUNCATE. It works like drop but only data. Columns with their name remain.

```
async def get_coins_api_postgres():
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(f'postgresql://{settings.user}:{settings.password}@{settings.host}/{settings.db_name}')
    await conn.execute("TRUNCATE coins_info")
    page = 0    
    coin_market = cg.get_coins_markets(vs_currency='usd', per_page=250, page=page)
    df_market = pd.DataFrame(coin_market,columns=['market_cap_rank','id','name','current_price',"price_change_24h","price_change_percentage_24h",'market_cap',"market_cap_change_percentage_24h",'total_volume',  "circulating_supply", "max_supply", "high_24h", "low_24h", ])
    tuples = list(df_market.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
    await conn.copy_records_to_table('coins_info', records=tuples, columns=list(df_market), timeout=10)
    await conn.close()
```